EF Core Navigation Property Creating Circular Reference Issue On Delete
I have a scenario I haven't seen before and I can't seem to find an answer on it. Could be improper configuration or something else.
I have two tables in a mysql database, one table is called Teams and another table is called TeamStats, in a one to many relationship with foreign keys, below are a short version of the table layouts:
Teams
  Id,
  Title,
  CurrentTeamStatsId,
  ...

TeamStats
  Id,
  TeamId,
  ...

On the Entity for Team I have a navigation property called CurrentTeamStats which points to TeamStats so that I can get the most recent record easily. I Have the configuration as follows for that property:
 entity.HasOne(c => c.CurrentTeamStats)
            .WithOne(p => p.Team)
            .HasForeignKey<Team>(c => c.CurrentTeamStatsId);

When I go to delete a team, an exception is being raised
Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE: Adding entities and configs
public partial class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int GameSheetsId { get; set; }
    public int LeagueSeasonId { get; set; }
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public int? LevelId { get; set; }
    public int? AssociationId { get; set; }
    public string? TeamLogo { get; set; }
    public string? Slug { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentTeamStatsId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastGameImport { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> GamesHome { get; set; } = new List<Game>();

    public virtual ICollection<Game> GamesAway { get; set; } = new List<Game>();
    
    public virtual ICollection<TeamRanking> TeamRankings { get; set; } = new List<TeamRanking>();

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Game> Games
    {
        get
        {
            List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
            games.AddRange(GamesHome);
            games.AddRange(GamesAway);
            return games;
        }
    }

    public virtual Level? Level { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
    public virtual Association? Association { get; set; }
    public virtual Division? Division { get; set; }
    public virtual Conference? Conference { get; set; }
    public virtual LeagueSeason? Season { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamStat? CurrentTeamStats { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TeamStat>? TeamStats { get; set; } = new List<TeamStat>();
}

public partial class TeamStat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Losses { get; set; }
    public int Ties { get; set; }
    public int OvertimeWins { get; set; }
    public int OvertimeLosses { get; set; }
    public int GoalsFor { get; set; }
    public int GoalsAgainst { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int GoalDifferential => GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst;
    public int? ShotsOnGoal { get; set; }
    public double? Rpi { get; set; }
    public double? GoalDifferentialRating { get; set; }
    public double? AverageGoalDifferential { get; set; }
    public double? AverageGoalDifferentialRating { get; set; }
    public double? HscRating { get; set; }
    public DateTime RunDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Team? Team { get; set; }
}

public partial class TeamConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");

        entity.ToTable("teams");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("id");
        entity.Property(e => e.LeagueSeasonId)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("leagueseasonid");
        entity.Property(e => e.DivisionId)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("divisionid");
        entity.Property(e => e.AssociationId)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("associationid");
        entity.Property(e => e.GameSheetsId)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("gamesheetsid");
        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .HasColumnName("name");
        entity.Property(e => e.TeamLogo)
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .HasColumnName("teamlogo");
        entity.Property(e => e.Slug)
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .HasColumnName("slug");
        entity.Property(e => e.CurrentTeamStatsId)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("currentteamstatsid");
        entity.Property(e => e.LastGameImport)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("lastgameimport");
        entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("updatedon")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("createdon")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Division);

        entity.HasOne(c => c.Conference);
        
        entity.HasOne(s => s.Season);
        
        entity.HasOne(l => l.Level);

        entity.HasMany(hg => hg.GamesHome)
            .WithOne(p => p.Home)
            .HasForeignKey(hg => hg.HomeId);

        entity.HasOne(c => c.CurrentTeamStats)
            .WithOne(p => p.Team)
            .HasForeignKey<Team>(c => c.CurrentTeamStatsId);
        
        entity.HasOne(a => a.Association)
            .WithMany(a => a.Teams)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.AssociationId);
        
    }
}

public partial class TeamConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TeamStat>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TeamStat> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");

        entity.ToTable("teamstats");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("id");
        entity.Property(e => e.TeamId)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("teamid");
        entity.Property(e => e.Wins)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("wins");
        entity.Property(e => e.Losses)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("losses");
        entity.Property(e => e.Ties)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("ties");
        entity.Property(e => e.OvertimeLosses)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("overtimelosses");
        entity.Property(e => e.OvertimeWins)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("overtimewins");
        entity.Property(e => e.Ties)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("ties");
        entity.Property(e => e.ShotsOnGoal)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("shotsongoal");
        entity.Property(e => e.GoalsFor)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("goalsfor");
        entity.Property(e => e.GoalsAgainst)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("goalsagainst");
        entity.Property(e => e.Rpi)
            .HasColumnType("double")
            .HasColumnName("rpi");
        entity.Property(e => e.GoalDifferentialRating)
            .HasColumnType("double")
            .HasColumnName("goaldifferentialrating");
        entity.Property(e => e.AverageGoalDifferential)
            .HasColumnType("double")
            .HasColumnName("averagegoaldifferential");
        entity.Property(e => e.AverageGoalDifferentialRating)
            .HasColumnType("double")
            .HasColumnName("averagegoaldifferentialrating");
        entity.Property(e => e.HscRating)
            .HasColumnType("double")
            .HasColumnName("hscrating");
        entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("updatedon")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("createdon")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        
    }
}


Please show both class declarations. Also any other config for those classes.

@Charlieface done.

Well you do indeed have a circular dependency. TeamStat is in a many-to-one relationship with Team but Team itself has a one-to-one relationship back to TeamStat via CurrentTeamStat. This is a rather unusual database design, where you'd first need to insert the Team, then the TeamStat, then set the CurrentTeamStat. Normally you would have a IsCurrent boolean on TeamStat (and enforce that via a filtered unique index/constraint) or you would have a Temporal Table design.

My goal with adding CurrentTeamStat was that I could easily pull back the most recent record. I am open to changing. Any idea on how to do that more easily.

I gave you two options already: an IsCurrent column, or a Temporal Table (I don't think MySQL supports this natively, you may have to use triggers etc to get the same).

My apologies. Thank you for that.
